# Python: Comparing values of three lists to create new list

Tags: python, list, compare, append

I am trying to compare the values of three lists in python, and create a new list based off of those comparisons.  To make it more confusing, the third list counts (+1) when a statement = true.

For example:

```
list1 = [5,10,15,20,25]
list2 = [3,6,9,12,15]
list3 = [0,1,11,21,28]
list4 = []

if list1 >= list3 and list2 <= list3:
    list4 = 0
else:
    list4 = list4 + 1
```

So list4 should look like:
list4[1,2,0,1,2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you comparing these element-wise?  If so, how do you get a result of `2`?

Comment: A result of 2 would be derived from list3 not being inside the range of list1, and list2 (list1 >= list3 and list2 <= list3).  Every time that condition is not true, a +1 count should be added to the list.  When list3 meets the conditions listed above, the list resets back to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!  The solutions worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator) and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
def solve(list1, list2, list3):
    last = 0
    for a, b, c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
        if a >= c and b <= c:
            yield 0
            last = 0
        else:
            last += 1     
            yield last
...             
>>> list(solve(list1, list2, list3))
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [5,10,15,20,25]
list2 = [3,6,9,12,15]
list3 = [0,1,11,21,28]
answer = []

app = 0
for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    if a>=c>=b:
        app = 0
    else:
        app += 1
    answer.append(app)
```

Proof:

```
>>> list1 = [5,10,15,20,25]
>>> list2 = [3,6,9,12,15]
>>> list3 = [0,1,11,21,28]
>>> answer = []
>>> 
>>> app = 0
>>> for a,b,c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
...     if a>=c>=b:
...         app = 0
...     else:
...         app += 1
...     answer.append(app)
... 
>>> answer
[1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```