# Pandas - Compare values of multiple dataframes, and keep the majority value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes with several columns (examples provided below).

I would like to compare the values of each cell across all 3 dataframes. If more than 2 dataframes have the same entry, I want to keep that entry. If there is no majority opinion, I would like the entry to read "no_majority"

Here are the examples:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"item": {0: "banana", 1: "orange", 2: "apple"},
                     "value": {0: "label1", 1: "label6", 2: "label1"}})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({"item": {0: "banana", 1: "orange", 2: "apple"},
                     "value": {0: "label2", 1: "label5", 2: "label1"}})

df_3 = pd.DataFrame({"fruit": {0: "banana", 1: "orange", 2: "apple"},
                     "value": {0: "label1", 1: "label4", 2: "label1"}})
```

And the expected output:

```
expected_out = pd.DataFrame({"fruit": {0: "banana", 1: "orange", 2: "apple"},
                     "value": {0: "label1", 1: "no_majority", 2: "label1"}})

expected_out
```

How can I do this? Asides from the index and `item` column, I want every observation to be compared across all 3 dataframes.

Thanks!

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343843/python-comparing-values-of-three-lists-to-create-new-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `concat` all dataframe then `groupby` and check `mode()` of `value` column in each group

```py
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2, df_3.rename(columns={'fruit': 'item'})], ignore_index=True)
out = (df.groupby('item')
       .apply(lambda g: 'no_majority' if len(g['value'].mode()) == 3 else g['value'].mode().item())
       .to_frame('value').reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'item': 'fruit'}))
```

```
print(out)

    fruit        value
0   apple       label1
1  banana       label1
2  orange  no_majority
```

Comment: How would this work in a case where there are multiple ```value``` columns?

Comment: @maxipod That would be another question depending on what you want for each value column

Comment: It's still the same concept as the column for ```value``` (the mode is selected). Basically, I don't have just one ```value``` column that I want this concept to apply to... I have several